# SQL SELECT composite primary key

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables ***User1*** and ***Relationship*** and it's some kind of user-friends relationship. I need to find all the friends of a user.

For example: I have a user with `ID=3` and I need to find all the users who have `Relationship.STATUS = 1` with this user.

FYI, I'm a beginner in SQL, so I know it's quite simple task but I can't handle it.

I’ve tried to use JOIN but it wasn't successfully.

```
SELECT *
FROM USER1
         RIGHT JOIN RELATIONSHIP R on USER1.USER1_ID = R.USER_ID_FROM OR USER1.USER1_ID = R.USER_ID_TO
WHERE R.USER_ID_FROM = :id
   OR R.USER_ID_TO = :id AND R.STATUS = :status AND USER1_ID != :id;
```

My tables:

```
TABLE USER1
(
    USER1_ID     NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    USER_NAME    NVARCHAR2(64),
    REAL_NAME    NVARCHAR2(64),
    EMAIL        NVARCHAR2(64),
    PHONE_NUMBER NVARCHAR2(64),
    BIRTH_DATE   TIMESTAMP,
    POST_ID      NUMBER,
    PASSWORD     NVARCHAR2(16)

);

TABLE RELATIONSHIP
(
    USER_ID_FROM NUMBER NOT NULL,
    USER_ID_TO   NUMBER NOT NULL,
    STATUS       SMALLINT DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT FK_USER_ONE FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID_FROM) REFERENCES USER1 (USER1_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_USER_TWO FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID_TO) REFERENCES USER1 (USER1_ID),
    CONSTRAINT PK_RELATIONSHIP PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID_FROM, USER_ID_TO)

);
```

Comment: Mixing AND and OR requires some care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the ids then you can use conditional logic to which which of the user ids you want:

```
select (case when user_id_from = 1 then user_id_to else user_id_from
        end) as other_user_id
from relationship r
where 1 in (user_id_from, user_id_to) and
      status = 3;
```

If you actually want all the user information, I would suggests `exists`:

```
select u.*
from user1 u
where exists (select 1
              from relationship r
              where r.status = 3 and
                    ( (r.user_id_from = 1 and r.user_id_to = u.id) or
                      (r.user_id_to = 1 and r.user_id_from = u.id)
                    )
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

Hum not sure but I would try something like this:

```
SELECT u.* FROM USER1 u LEFT JOIN RELATIONSHIP r ON r.USER_ID_FROM = :id AND r.STATUS = 1 AND u.USER1_ID = r.USER_ID_TO;
```

Where the id is the ID of the user you want to find the friends.

Comment: a and b are poor table aliases. Chose something that makes sense, like `r` for `RELATIONSHIP`.

Comment: Thank you for helping but your answer is incorrect. In this case I get not all the user friends.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM USER1 U
LEFT JOIN RELATIONSHIP R ON R.USER_ID_FROM = U.ID AND R.[STATUS] = 1
LEFT JOIN USER1 F ON R.[USER_ID_TO] = F.[ID]
WHERE U.[Id] = your_id
```

Then simply filter the users. Left join is used because a user may not have any friends. And I understood that you want to find the user and any friends for that users.

Comment: Thanks for helping me but it still wrong answer. In this case I get only one user with ID{your_id}

Comment: Still I get only one user friend except of two.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(SELECT *
FROM USER1 u
LEFT JOIN RELATIONSHIP f ON u.USER1_ID = f.USER_ID_FROM
WHERE f.USER_ID_TO= 3 AND f.STATUS = 1)
union
(SELECT *
FROM USER1 o
LEFT JOIN RELATIONSHIP t ON o.USER1_ID = t.USER_ID_TO
WHERE t.USER_ID_FROM= 3 AND t.STATUS = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks fr your answer. About the table:
Row {USER_ID_FROM} - collects user ID who send request for a friendship for another User;
Row {USER_ID_TO} - collects user ID who is a receive for the requests
Row {STATUS} - it's curent status of their relationship 0 - Pending, 1 - Accepted/Friends, 2 - Declined, 3 - Deleted

About your answer - unfortunately it has return not all of user friends.

Comment: If I'm not wrong it will return all "accepted" friends of the user with id "3"

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks. But, to be honestly, this request looks so heavy and complex. Is there a way to simplify it?